# How do I get the ID of the LI item that was just deleted in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to get the ID of the LI item that was deleted.  Here is my code below:

```
            // when the user wants to just trash a task compeletely
        $(".ui-icon-trash").on("click", function(e) {
            var id = $(this).parent("li");
            // var idVal = id.getAttribute("id");

            tb_show("Warning!", "#TB_inline?height=100&width=260&inlineId=divDelete", "");
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent("li").remove();
        });
```

The problem is that id.getAttribute("id") returns undefined.

My LI attribute looks like this:

```
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" id="1">
            <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Task</h5>
            <img src="graphics/task.png" width="96" height="72" />
            Sample Task
            <a href="" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
            <a href="" title="Delete task" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete task</a>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// when the user wants to just trash a task compeletely
    $(".ui-icon-trash").on("click", function(e) {
        var id = $(this).parent("li");
        // var idVal = id.getAttribute("id");

        tb_show("Warning!", "#TB_inline?height=100&width=260&inlineId=divDelete", "");
        e.preventDefault();
        var myVar = $(this).parent("li").attr("id");
        $(this).parent("li").remove();
    });
```

myVar should return the ID of the deleted element

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can do this:

```
var id = $(this).parent("li").attr('id')
```

Or vanilla JS mixed with jQ:

```
var id = $(this).parent("li")[0].id
```

Comment: vanilla JS would be `var id = this.parentNode.id`